# center table with css when table cells wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to centre something with two "cells".  I've managed to do it with "inline-block" and "table-column", but there are issues when the area is too narrow and a cell's content wraps.  With inline-block, the width is the width of the container and it doesn't wrap until it's too late.  With table-column, it wraps fine, but then it's no longer centred.

How can I get the form to be centred when the li is narrow?

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/V4J8y/

CSS:

```css
/*horizontal the jquery mobile 1.4.2 way removes icons, so hack it in*/
.horizontal-with-icons .ui-checkbox {
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <form style="display: table; margin: 0px auto;">
            <!--TODO: center when narrow-->
            <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">Bedrooms:</div>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="horizontal-with-icons" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <label>
                    <input id="bedroom-1" type="checkbox" />1</label>
                <label>
                    <input id="bedroom-2" type="checkbox" />2</label>
                <label>
                    <input id="bedroom-3" type="checkbox" />3</label>
                <label>
                    <input id="bedroom-4" type="checkbox" />4</label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: duplicate code.  different question (with hopefully a different answer)

Comment: my bad, vote retracted :)